# issue regarding inheritance and circular dependencies

Tags: c#, inheritance, dll

Ran across a very interesting problem at work yesterday.

I have 2 different classes named Foo and Bar. Each sitting in their own C# library project (separate dlls).

Bar contains a virtual method:

```
public class Bar
{
     public virtual void DoSomething();
}
```

Foo uses an instance of Bar in its constructor to set an internal property:

```
public Foo (Bar myBar)
{
      m_Bar = myBar;
}
```

Obviously, Foo has a reference to Bar's project.

Now, I have 5 other classes each of which also sits in its own project/dll. We'll call them A, B, C, D, and E. A-E are all subclassed from class Bar and each of them contain their own overridden implementation of DoSomething(). Because they are subclassed from Bar, any of them are valid as parameters for Foo's constructor.

A-E each maintain an inner collection of Foo instances. For example I would do something like this inside of Class A:

```
myFooCollection.Add(new Foo(this));
```

For this reason classes A-E all require a reference to Foo's project/dll.

Now, switching back to Foo for a moment lets say after setting the Bar property in the constructor I need to call the DoSomething() method of that Bar:

```
public class Foo (Bar myBar)
{
     m_Bar = myBar;
     m_Bar.DoSomething();
}
```

Bear in mind for example that Class A was used as the Bar parameter for the constructor. My call to DoSomething() needs to execute A's implementation of that method. However, since the constructor argument is of the parent class Bar and Foo has no knowledge of class A-E (I can't give it a reference without causing circular dependency) it will call the virtual method in the parent class Bar. The natural solution would be to downcast to the child class before making the call:

```
(A)m_Bar.DoSomething();
```

But this is out of the question as well since once again, Foo has no knowledge of this set of child classes. So here is my dilemma. The overall project structure cannot change because obviously the system is much bigger and more complex than what I've presented here. But my requirements are still the same. Foo needs to be able to reach the child implementation of DoSomething() in order to function properly. Any thoughts on how to solve this? If any clarification is required in better understanding the problem let me know and I will try and elaborate further.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that using Reflection to derive the child type at runtime isn't a valid solution to this problem in the context of my system.

Comment: Can you include your method stubs for your subclassed Bar.DoSomething methods()?

Comment: Sorry but I can't share something like that online as it is for work. The method stubs shouldn't change the overall problem.

Comment: This should all work fine. Maybe just create a test solution following all the rules you've laid out in your question (i.e. simple classes in three different projects, A-E). Do you get the same result?

Comment: What syntax is being used  for overridding in your subclassed DoSomething() methods? override or new?

Comment: I'm attempting to create a simple solution to recreate the problem.

Comment: If you're using new in your subclasses, that is likely going to be the  cause of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to have static circular references of projects; however, you can have dynamic circular references of instances. If you call `m_Bar.DoSomething();` then, because of polymorphy, the right implementataion will be called automatically. If `m_Bar` is a `Bar` then `Bar`'s implementation will be called. If `m_Bar` is a `A` then `A`'s implementation will be called. Neither `Bar` nor `Foo` need to know the existing of the classes `A` through `E`.

---

UPDATE: (see comments below)

```
public class A : Bar
{
     public override void DoSomething()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("I am an 'A'");
     }
}
```

Comment: This is what I assumed when I started work on this however I verified very carefully that after constructing an instance of Foo using A and then calling DoSomething it called the parent method and no polymorphism took place

Comment: This cannot be. If you have overridden `DoSomething` in derived classes (not just created a new `DoSomething` method). Then the overridden method will be called. You must use the `override` keyword, not the `new` keyword. (Note: By typing "override" inellisense presents you a list of overridable methods and properties and creates an overridden method or property automatically for you.)

Comment: I just wrote out a simple console application and what you're saying is true (this is what I had expected to happen from the first place and was shocked when it didn't). I must have missed something that was causing this to happen. Perhaps it was a new vs an override but I have since moved on to make significant other changes so it is hard to go back and check what was missed.